# How to track time using zeitgeist in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, zeitgeist, time-management

I have no clue how to use `zeitgeist` after installing it with `apt`. It seems to be a tracker that dumps the data somewhere but there is no viewer!! The so called “GNOME Activity Journal” and `zeitgeist-explorer` are not found in `apt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this `zeitgeist-explorer` package with dependencies from 18.04 LTS [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/zeitgeist-explorer) and install it manually with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/z/zeitgeist/python-zeitgeist_1.0-0.1ubuntu1_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/z/zeitgeist-explorer/zeitgeist-explorer_0.2-1.1_all.deb

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ./python-zeitgeist_1.0-0.1ubuntu1_all.deb ./zeitgeist-explorer_0.2-1.1_all.deb
```

and then use as it was planned.